# Why does ConnMan report my MAC address as all zeros until I restart it?

Tags: linux, networking, mac-address

ConnMan (Connection-Manager) reports my ethernet adapter's MAC address as 00:00:00:00:00:00. However, if I restart the ConnMan service using

```
$ systemctl restart connman.service
```

it subsequently reports the MAC address as the actual address. **Why does ConnMan report the ethernet adapter's MAC as zero until restarted?**

The actual MAC address is passed from U-Boot to the kernel via kernel boot parameter *ethaddr*, and ifconfig always reports it rather than zeros.

I'm using the Angstrom distribution with ConnMan version 1.25.